# Value is not being added in text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, viewstate

I have the following code that i found on this tutorial:

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/04/adding-dynamic-rows-in-gridview-with-textboxes.aspx

Default.aspx

```
<asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Header 3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if (!Page.IsPostBack){
            SetInitialRow();  
        }
}


private void SetInitialRow(){

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3", typeof(string)));

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Column1"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column2"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Column3"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;

        Gridview1.DataSource = dt;
        Gridview1.DataBind();
}

private void AddNewRowToGrid(){

        int rowIndex =0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1; 
                    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
                    drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                //add new row to DataTable
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                //Store the current data to ViewState
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                //Rebind the Grid with the current data
                Gridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                Gridview1.DataBind();
           }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
}

private void SetPreviousData(){

        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
                    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
                    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");


                    box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column1"].ToString();
                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column2"].ToString();
                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Column3"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;

                }
            }
        }
}

protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        AddNewRowToGrid();
}
```

Now the issue is, lets say when the inital grid comes up and i add some data and then click add row. The data i added in that row stays there ok. But now, lets say i added 5 rows, and then i go to row number 3 and i add some data and click add row, that data disappears and never shows up. The data will only show up if i add data on the last row and then click add row. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Where is `ButtonAdd_Click`?  How does `AddNewRowToGrid` get called?

Comment: its on the onclick event for the button in the footer template

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - at the very bottom of the posted code.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening, because of this loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //extract the TextBox values
    TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
    TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
    TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
    drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = i + 1; 
    drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
    drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
    drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;

    rowIndex++;
}
```

It is going through all the rows in the data table and building a `drCurrentRow` object, but it is only adding the `drCurrentRow` object outside of the loop:

```
//add new row to DataTable
dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
```

Therefore the contents of `drCurrentRow` are the last row.

UPDATE:

To address this issue, I recommend that you make it so only one row can be added a time and then instead of looping through all of the rows in the data table, just get the data from the last row and use that as the data for the "new" row to add to the data table, like this:

```
//extract the TextBox values
TextBox box1 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].FindControl("TextBox1");
TextBox box2 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox2");
TextBox box3 = (TextBox)Gridview1.Rows[dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox3");

drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
drCurrentRow["RowNumber"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1; 
drCurrentRow["Column1"] = box1.Text;
drCurrentRow["Column2"] = box2.Text;
drCurrentRow["Column3"] = box3.Text;

//add new row to DataTable
dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
```

Comment: @BradHazelnut - I would suggest making it so only one row at a time can be added to the grid. And instead of looping through all of the rows, just use the data from the last item in the data table to populate the "new" row. See `UPDATE:` in my answer.